# Java Buffered Reader in Loop

Tags: java

I am trying to create a JAVA program that reads some tags from a txt file and creates objects that have these tags as fields. I am posting the part of the code that I have the issue :

```
try{
        line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null){
            if (!line.trim().equals(" ") && line.trim().equals("ITEM_LIST")) {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line != null && line.trim().equals("{"))) {
                            line = reader.readLine();
                            if (line != null) {
                                if (line.trim().equals("ITEM")) {
                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                    if (line != null) {
                                        if (line.trim().equals("{")) {
                                            if (line != null) {
                                                line = reader.readLine();
                                                while (!((line.trim().startsWith("ITEM_TYPE ")) {
                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if((line.trim().startsWith("ITEM_TYPE ")){
                                                        String devType = line.trim().substring(10);
                                                    }
                                                )
                                                if(devType.toLowerCase() == "tv"){
                                                    dev = new TV();
                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("CODE ")) {
                                                            dev.setCode(line.substring(5).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("MODEL ")) {
                                                            dev.setModelName(line.substring(6).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("MODEL_YEAR ")) {
                                                            dev.setYear(line.substring(11).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("MANUFACTURER ")) {
                                                            dev.setConstructor(line.substring(13).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("PRICE ")) {
                                                            dev.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(line.substring(6).trim()));
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("PANEL_TYPE ")) {
                                                            dev.setType(line.substring(11).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("DIMENSIONS ")) {
                                                            dev.setSize(line.substring(11).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("RESOLUTION ")) {
                                                            dev.setResolution(line.substring(10).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("INTERFACES ")) {
                                                            dev.setPorts(line.substring(10).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                                    if (line != null){
                                                        if (line.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith("PIECES ")) {
                                                            dev.setPieces(line.substring(7).trim());
                                                        }
                                                    }
```

My question is how can I modify the code in order to read the tag `ITEM_TYPE` first of all then create the specific item (e.g. tv) and then read all the other tags and complete the object. The order of the tags in the txt file is not specific and if a tag is missing the field will take a default value. Here is the txt file :

```
  ITEM_LIST
{
ITEM
{
    CODE ADLS443
    ITEM_TYPE tv
    MODEL IDL32KJX4300
    MODEL_YEAR 2016
    MANUFACTURER Samsung
    PRICE 350
    PANEL_TYPE LCD
    DIMENSIONS 32
    RESOLUTION "Full HD"
    INTERFACES "HDMI USB SCART"
    PIECES 43
}
ITEM
{
    CODE KD444211
    ITEM_TYPE tv
    MODEL KDL49DDR4600
    MODEL_YEAR 2014
    MANUFACTURER Sony
    PRICE 600
    PANEL_TYPE LED
    DIMENSIONS 49
    RESOLUTION "Ultra HD"
    INTERFACES "HDMI USB SCART Ethernet WiFi"
    PIECES 8
}
ITEM
{
    CODE 2445DBS41
    ITEM_TYPE blueray
    MODEL JVX44R32
    MODEL_YEAR 2012
    MANUFACTURER LG
    PRICE 250
    RESOLUTION 1080p
    FORMAT BR-W
    PIECES 12
}
```

I'm sorry if any information about the code is missing.

Comment: if (!line.trim().equals(" ")) {  if (line.trim().equals("ITEM_LIST")) { => if (!line.trim().equals(" ") && line.trim().equals("ITEM_LIST")) {

Comment: same thing for if (line != null) { if (line.trim().equals("{")) { use the end operator as you don't have any else

Comment: First of all I dont understand what do you mean with your first comment,If you want to say something just say it. Secondly, your comment doesnt answer to my question at all and at last I do not use the end operator because as I said i am posting a part of the code, my if statement is not done .

Comment: I seriously recommend reading some relevant literature such as [Clean code](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882). What Nicolas is hinting at is that nesting `if` blocks like you did is a terrible code smell and such code won't be testable, maintainable or debuggable.

Comment: How will this help me?

Comment: Your code is simply not readable it is what I meant so I gave you tips to make it more readable which should help people to help you. As long as it is not readable I don't want to help and I believe that I'm not the only one. And comments are not answers, we use them to clarify the question if needed

Comment: Ok I changed those parts. I hope that it is more readable now

Comment: that's better even if there many other that you could fix, another remark don't compare String with == use equals I mean devType.toLowerCase() == "tv" => devType.toLowerCase().equals("tv")

Comment: Your code is simply not even compilable as is. There are extra closing parentheses everywhere, variables used after their enclosing scope has closed, all sorts of basic errors. Please correct and edit.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't.

Better answer - read everything under `ITEM`, extract `ITEM_TYPE`, create the object you want and fill it with the rest of the data.

Also, you may want to only do `line.trim()` once, right after you performed the `reader.readLine()`, and generally rewrite the code as a state machine so you won't have that high level of nesting `if`s.